# WordPress, массовая замена URL на страницах и в записях

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Имеется сайт на WP с почти 10 тыс. записей и есть необходимость изменить формат URL.

Ранее URL был типа %pageName%, сейчас необходимо изменить на %catName%/%pageName%, но проблема в том, что на сайте огромное количество статей которые ссылаются на другие страницы сайта и править их вручную просто невозможно. Существует ли способ изменить всех ссылки в записях на ссылки нового формата?

Comment: Если пермалинки меняются в первый раз, то редирект произойдет автоматом.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь поможет 301 Redirect. Для Wordpress есть парочка отличных плагинов: Simple 301 Redirects и Redirection (на ваш вкус). Настраиваются в пару кликов и не придётся прописывать в ничего самому в .htaccess